# Wireless stopped working after latest update on Precision 5510, 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, updates

I approved an update to my Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Precision 5510, and my wireless now does not work.  I followed the Ubuntu Help procedures; I typed

```
nm-tool
```

and got

```
NetworkManager Tool
State: disconnected
```

I typed

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

and after password prompt, I got:

```
*network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: Wireless 8260
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
version: 3a
width: 64 bits
clock:33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
configuation: latency=0
resources: memory:ddc00000-ddc01fff
```

So my wireless is 8260, v. 3a, fine; I went to Additional Drivers and selected one of the 8260 drivers but the non-8260 driver kept reverting to selected when I hit "Apply Changes".  I've since browsed the AskUbuntu forum and mashed in a bunch of different command lines scraped from other, similar problems, causing my original driver to disappear after I selected "do not use this device" and rebooted, and god knows what else, but in CL mode I am like a man in a dark room full of expensive things trying to find the light switch by swinging a baseball bat.  If nothing else, someone could tell me how to navigate to "restore factory settings" and at this point that will be good enough for me until I learn more about CL navigation.  Help!!!

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `uname -r` and also: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` By chance, did your Dell come with Ubuntu preinstalled?

Comment: Thanks for your input- I'm sorry to have left this hanging, but things have changed.  After visiting a computer technician, I installed 16.04 on my machine.  (It was preinstalled with 14.04)  Now the wireless card works fine, but the audio drivers are gone & I can't seem to figure out how to reinstall them and get them working again.  I'm seeing the technician again this Saturday & hopefully I'll learn how to fix these problems in the future.  I'll leave this up for a day, then delete the question.